# Missing return statment

Tags: java, if-statement, return

I wrote this small program as practice in Java(it simulates the 7 electrical logic gates), as I am currently learning it. But when I try to compile it, it gives me several errors stating `"MISSING RETURN STATEMENT"`, but only for the subroutines that have 2 if statements(AND, OR, NAND and NOR). I am wondering if there is something that I don't know about Java if statements. I am also wondering if there is a way in Java to do `if(X && Y)`, like in C. Anyway, here is the code:

```
package logic;
public class logic {
    boolean AND(boolean A, boolean B) {
        if(A==true) {
            if(B==true)
                return true;
        }
        else
            return false;
    }
    boolean OR(boolean A, boolean B) {
        if(A==false) {
            if(B==false)
                return false;
        }
        else
            return true;
    }
    boolean NOT(boolean A) {
        if(A==true)
            return false;
        else
            return true;
    }
    boolean NAND(boolean A, boolean B) {
        if(A==true) {
            if(B==true)
                return false;
        }
        else
            return true;
    }
    boolean NOR(boolean A, boolean B) {
        if(A==false) {
            if(B==false)
                return true;
        }
        else
            return false;
    }
    boolean XOR(boolean A, boolean B) {
        if(A==B)
            return false;
        else
            return true;
    }
    boolean XNOR(boolean A, boolean B) {
        if(A==B)
            return true;
        else
            return false;
    } 
}
```

and the error message:

```
logic/logic.java:10: error: missing return statement
    }
    ^
logic/logic.java:18: error: missing return statement
    }
    ^
logic/logic.java:32: error: missing return statement
    }
    ^
logic/logic.java:40: error: missing return statement
    }
    ^
4 errors
```

all help or suggestions is accepted.

For some reason when I tried to use `if(A==true && B==true)`before it didn't work, but now it is.

Comment: For `AND`, `return A && B`, for `OR`, `return A || B`, etc., or omit the functions altogether?

Comment: `A == true` is redundant and can be simplified to `A`.

Comment: @Dukeling Thats a matter of taste however

Comment: @RichardTingle Please, no. I'll obsessively remove `== true` or `== false` (obviously replace with `!...`) wherever I see it in any code I work on.

Comment: @RichardTingle `if (John.isHuman == true)` in words - "if John is human is true". I don't know about you, but that's not the way I speak, thus not the way I code. Though you have a point about `!something`, although it's only applicable to programmers new to such syntax, you get used to reading the `!` fast enough.

Comment: @RichardTingle `if (!updated) update()` - "if not updated, update". Makes sense to me. But yeah, coding style arguments rarely go anywhere, so we should probably stop now.

Comment: @Dukeling I think you're probably right, although we've managed to keep it civil which is nothing short of remarkable

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Missing return statement error means that The function declaration says it returns something, but there exists atleast one flow where it does not return anything. Eg. In the code for And - if A is true and B is false. Modified the code :

```
package logic;
public class Logic {
boolean AND(boolean A, boolean B) {
    if (A == true && B == true) {
        return true;
    }
    return false;
}

boolean OR(boolean A, boolean B) {
    if (A == false && B == false) {
        return false;
    }
    return true;
}

boolean NOT(boolean A) {
    if (A == true) {
        return false;
    }
    return true;
}

boolean NAND(boolean A, boolean B) {
    if (A == true && B == true) {
        return false;
    }
    return true;
}

boolean NOR(boolean A, boolean B) {
    if (A == false && B == false) {
        return true;
    }
    return false;
}

boolean XOR(boolean A, boolean B) {
    if (A == B) {
        return false;
    }
    return true;
}

boolean XNOR(boolean A, boolean B) {
    if (A == B) {
        return true;
    }
    return false;
}
```

}

Answer (score 3):

Java is not like Python where the compiler understand that code blocks are stated by simple indentation. I would recommend **always** using braces `{ }` to open a close a new code block **even if is one liner**. Just to rewrite one of your gates:

```
boolean AND(boolean A, boolean B) {
    if(A==true) {
        if(B==true) {
            return true;
        }
        //missing return here!
        //fix it by adding a return
        return false;
    } else {
        return false;
    }
}
```

Comment: +1 For that recommendation , it can save the life of a programmer !

Comment: @TheNewIdiot yes, this is heavily recommended when doing Java programming.

Comment: -1 Since everything you wrote has to do with coding style (which is personal preference) and really has nothing to do with the error (although you have a comment in your code about the error). If you made it a footnote, it'd have been fine.

Comment: @Dukeling in fact, the problem here was the coding style. Otherwise, there wouldn't has been any error. By reading the code you can see that this is an `if-else` exercise meant to confuse students and teaching them the importance of the braces usage. And for this specific case, the coding style **matters**.

Comment: I find your last comment hard to take in given the `A == true` and `B == true` statements above. Even if it was their original code.

Comment: @HunterMcMillen I'm not juding OP's methods implementation, just the problem was done by misusage of braces, otherwise I would have rewritten all the class as done in [Kechit Goyal's answer](http://stackoverflow.com/a/17619384/1065197) or [winne2's answer](http://stackoverflow.com/a/17619428/1065197).

Comment: @LuiggiMendoza The code was properly indented in the question, so I find it improbable that OP could've noticed the missing return with the braces but not without the braces. If the first `if` didn't have braces either, **that** would've been a classic `if-else` question. I would've accepted it (although still not agreed with your recommendation) had you actually explained the problem followed by pretty much exactly what you wrote. Feel free to edit it if you want your 2 reputation back.

Answer (score 2):

As others have pointed out, you really miss out some return statements. Here is the short version you are looking for:

```
public class Logic {
    boolean AND(boolean A, boolean B) {
        return A && B;
    }
    boolean OR(boolean A, boolean B) {
        return A || B;
    }
    boolean NOT(boolean A) {
        return !A;
    }
    boolean NAND(boolean A, boolean B) {
        return !(A && B);
    }
    boolean NOR(boolean A, boolean B) {
        return !(A || B);
    }
    boolean XOR(boolean A, boolean B) {
        return A ^ B;
    }
    boolean XNOR(boolean A, boolean B) {
        return !(A ^ B);
    } 
}
```

Note that class names in Java should start with a capital letter by convention.

Comment: Why not compose these? You already wrote NOT, OR, XOR, and AND. You can build XNOR, NOR, and NAND from those. Technically, you can build everything from a NAND gate.

Comment: Sure, and you could also compose XOR as OR(AND(A, NOT(B)), AND(B, NOT(A))). I guess I choose this answer for efficiency reasons (minimize expensive function calls).

Answer (score 1):

Some of your methods have paths that result in no return value.

For example:

```
boolean NOR(boolean A, boolean B) {
            if(A==false) {
                if(B==false)
                    return true;
            }
            else
                return false;
        }
```

If A == false and B == true, there is no return statement to run. This is why you are getting that compiler error.

This is perhaps made more obvious by putting brackets around all of your if statements:

```
boolean NOR(boolean A, boolean B) {
            if(A==false) 
            {
                if(B==false)
                {
                    return true;
                }
                //No return here
            }
            else
            {
                return false;
            }

            //No return here
        }
```

Comment: Your second "No return here" is wrong. There not being a return is fine, since there is no branch that can get there.

Comment: @Dukeling What do you mean? There is no return statement there, so there are branches that have no return statement as a result. If A == false, and B == true it will get there.

Comment: @thatidiotguy There is an implicit empty else here, it returns nothing if the inner if statement is false

Comment: @LuiggiMendoza whaaaaaat? The else is matched with the first if! Am I crazy??? His inner if is enclosed in brackets.

Comment: I suppose technically you need *either* the first  "//No return here" or the second "//No return here" but not simultaneously both

Comment: @LuiggiMendoza Phew, I thought I was going crazy. I have been doing Java for years and missing something like this would make me question every program I have ever written.

Answer (score 1):

You lack return statements for some code paths.

In `OR`, what happens if A is true and B is false?

Answer (score 1):

Aside from the return statement errors, you are making your code way too complex. Java already has compound logical operators that can greatly simplify how you are reasoning about your program.

```
// no need for A == true, A is either already true or false
// just combine them using the && operator
boolean AND(boolean A, boolean B) {
   return A && B;
}
```

Similarly for OR:

```
boolean OR(boolean A, boolean B) {
   return A || B;
}
```

You can also build logic gates from other logic gates, EX NOT + OR == NOR

```
boolean NOT(boolean A) {
   return !A;
}

boolean OR(boolean A, boolean B) {
   return A || B;
}
```

Combine the two to create NOR:

```
boolean NOR(boolean A, boolean B) {
   return NOT( OR(A, B) );
}
```

Using this, see if you can compose the rest yourself.

Comment: @arshajii There wasn't a need for functions in the first place, *but* since they are being use this is much simpler.

Comment: Cool! I don't know that much about logic gates in the first place :P. What exactly does `A || B` do?

Comment: @user2576988 Its the or gate you're trying to write, pure and simple

Comment: @user2576988 `||` in Java (and many other langauges) is the operator that computes logical `OR` which is exactly the gate you are trying to model. Take a look at the Java operator list: http://docs.oracle.com/javase/tutorial/java/nutsandbolts/opsummary.html

Answer (score 0):

There are possible values that could result in no value being returned, remember an `if` has an empty `else{}` whether you give it one or not, so lets look at one of your functions

```
boolean AND(boolean A, boolean B) {
    if(A==true) {
        if(B==true)
            return true;
        }else{
              //else made explicit by me
              //NO RETURN
        }
    }
    else{
        return false;
    }
}
```

So if A was true but B was false *nothing* would be returned, the compiler cannot allow this

Its also unwise to use the multiline-braceless-if because it makes it easier to make these sorts of error. See http://cafe.elharo.com/blogroll/braceless-if-considered-harmful/

Answer (score 0):

you must have a return statement for all possible "paths". For example

```
boolean AND(boolean A, boolean B) {
        if(A==true) {
            if(B==true)
                return true;
        }
        else
            return false;
    }
```

is equivalent to

```
boolean AND(boolean A, boolean B) {
        if(A==true) {
            if(B==true)
                return true;
            else
                //something must be returned here
        }
        else
            return false;
    }
```

You can also have a return null; statement at the end of every method to avoid this error.

Comment: Its worth adding that using the multiline-braceless-if is considered bad practice